# Using CRM 4.0 SDK to send emails to multiple contacts at once

Tags: email, crm, dynamics-crm-4

Is it possible to send out an email with multiple email addresses specified in the "to" field? I have it working for single recipients, but can't figure out how to send to multiple, here is my current code for emailing a single user:

```
 public static void sendCRMNotification(string userGuid, string emailSubject, string emailBody, string recipientType) 

{  

//Set up CRM service
crmService crmservice = GetCrmService();

// Create a FROM activity party for the email.
activityparty fromParty = new activityparty();
fromParty.partyid = new Lookup();
fromParty.partyid.type = EntityName.systemuser.ToString();
fromParty.partyid.Value = new Guid(/*guid of sending user*/);

//Create a TO activity party for email
activityparty toParty = new activityparty();
toParty.partyid = new Lookup();
toParty.partyid.type = EntityName.contact.ToString();
toParty.partyid.Value = new Guid(userGuid);

//Create a new email
email emailInstance = new email();

//set email parameters
emailInstance.from = new activityparty[] { fromParty };
emailInstance.to = new activityparty[] { toParty };
emailInstance.subject = emailSubject;
emailInstance.description = emailBody;

//Create a GUId for the email
Guid emailId = crmservice.Create(emailInstance);

//Create a SendEmailRequest
SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest();
request.EmailId = emailId;
request.IssueSend = true;
request.TrackingToken = "";

 //Execute request
crmservice.Execute(request);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have done in the past.  Create the array in the beginning before you set it to the email property.

```
activityparty[] toParty = new activityparty[2];
    toParty[0] = new activityparty();
    toParty[0].partyid = new Lookup(EntityName.contact.ToString(), userGuid);

    toParty[1] = new activityparty();
    toParty[1].partyid = new Lookup(EntityName.contact.ToString(), anotherUserGuid);

    emailMessage.to = toParty;
```